# Android Getting Public Transport in Google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gtfs

I know there is available api in json format for traveing by public transport instead of driving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one from Google. A number of transit agencies release their transit data in Google Transit Feed Spec (GTFS) format. Here's a list of some of the agencies that do:
http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds

Here's more on GTFS:
http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html